# Is there a way to possibly join any two columns in hibernate using some criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate

Since I'm new to Hibernate, I am not sure how one can join two columns using criteria.

I tried using @nativeQuery but wasn't successful. I am quite unsure why it  throws an invalid column error. However, I need to implement it using some criteria and restrictions.

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = "awardEligiblePartner",
                query = "select aep.PRTNR_AWRD_TYPE_CD as benefitId, pat.PRTNR_AWRD_THRLD_TYPE_CD as benefitType from AWRD_ELIG_PRTNR aep, PRTNR_AWRD_THRLD pat where aep.PRTNR_AWRD_TYPE_CD = pat.PRTNR_AWRD_TYPE_CD and pat.PRTNR_AWRD_THRLD_TYPE_CD = 'ROUND_UP'",
                resultClass = AwardEligibilityPartner.class
        )
})
```

Can someone please help me solve the following query using constraints in Hibernate?

Comment: can you run that native query in your db ? Try checking if that works in your db

Comment: it is working as expected and I tried below criteria please correct me If I'm missing something

 Criteria awardEligiblePartnerCriteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(AwardEligibilityPartner.class, "awardEligiblePartner");
            awardEligiblePartnerCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("awardEligiblePartner.clientPrdctCD", clientPrdctCD));
            awardEligiblePartnerCriteria.createAlias("awardEligiblePartner.partnerAwardThrld", "partnerAwardThrld");
            awardEligiblePartnerCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("partnerAwardThrld.awardThrldTypeCD", "ROUND_UP"));

Comment: I'm seeing below error when I tried with above criteria 

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet